# Video Background w/ container

Tags: html, css, video

I am working on a new website that implements a video background. I have it set up so that it fills the height of the screen viewing the website. There's a container/row that comes up underneath the video that doesn't display until the user scrolls down. What I want to do is bring that container up so it is visible on the  [homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9ztY.jpg) without having to scroll down. Essentially, the user is just seeing the video background and navbar first without any content. I want to avoid that.

I use W3CSS.

```js
(function() {
   /*** Video element* @type {HTMLElement} */
   var video = document.getElementById("my-video");
   /*** Check if video can play, and play it */
   video.addEventListener( "canplay", function() {
    video.play();
   });
  })();
```

```css
.content {
/*    top: 70%;*/
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
    margin-top: -550px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.contain-header {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; 
    
}
.main-header {
    min-height:100vh;
    display:absolute;
    color:#fff; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
}
video#my-video {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    z-index:-100;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    background-size: cover;
}
video {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="contain-header">
 <div class="main-header">
  <video id="my-video" class="video" muted loop>
   <source src="http://media.istockphoto.com/videos/wheel-truck-video-id473253495" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
 </div>   
 <div class="w3-container w3-row w3-red w3-center w3-padding-16 content">
  <div class="w3-col l4">
   <h3>PICK YOUR TRUCK</h3>
   <p>We have the right truck for the load! <br>
   View Our Fleet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l4">
   <h3>WORK FOR US</h3>
   <p>Become a Freight Broker<br>
   View Benefits/Application</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-col l4">
   <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
   <p>Can't find what you're looking for?<br>
   Call/Email a Representative</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/xxdash/pen/MmxZgM)

Comment: Can you describe more about the result that you want? Do you want the red bar at the top of the video or the bottom? Do you want the red bar in front of the video?

Comment: @WhiteHotLoveTiger reattached the image! I want the red bar on the bottom in front of the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't completely understand why you'd want to obscure that cool background with that big red block so I made it semi-transparent.

### Changes

> ```
> .content {
>   top: 0;
>   position: absolute;
>   height:auto;
>   ...
> }
>
> .main-header {
>   z-index:-1;
>   ...
> }
>
> .l4 {
>    margin-top: 10%;
>   }
>
> .RED.RED {
>   background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, .3) !important;
> }
> ```

The last selector was doubled in order to override the `background-color` rule of `.w3-red`. I also was forced to use `!important` (not recommended) because one third of `w3.css` rulesets have `!important`. That's very inflexible and plain bad. Anyways the color is in rgba and the first 3 numbers are a red, green, blue composite color and the fourth number has a range of 0 to 1 opacity (0 is invisible and 1 is visible).

#### Added

- `.w3-mobile`     For responsiveness
- `.w3-hide-small` On the first 2 columns because you want to have only essential content in limited space
- `. w3-hide-medium` As above

#### Removed

- `.w3-contain`    Fixed width containers not responsive

#### Options

- If you still prefer the bar on the bottom, adjust the the following rule:

  - `.content { top: 0;...` to `{ bottom: 0;...`
- If you still prefer the bar to be more opaque, adjust the following rule:

  - `.RED.RED { background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, .1) !important; }` change the fourth number to the maximum of 1.

### Demo

```js
(function() {
  /*** Video element* @type {HTMLElement} */
  var video = document.getElementById("my-video");
  /*** Check if video can play, and play it */
  video.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
    video.play();
  });
})();
```

```css
.content {
  /* ADDED */
  top: 0;
  /* ADDED */
  position: absolute;
  /* ADDED */
  height: auto;
  z-index: 500;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.contain-header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-header {
  height: 100vh;
  display: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* ADDED */
  z-index: -1;
}

video#my-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-size: cover;
}

video {
  display: block;
}


/* ADDED ---------------------------*/

.l4 {
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.RED.RED {
  background-color: rgba(244, 67, 54, .1) !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="contain-header">
  <div class="main-header">
    <video id="my-video" class="video" muted loop>
   <source src="http://media.istockphoto.com/videos/wheel-truck-video-id473253495" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-bar w3-mobile w3-row w3-layout-row w3-red w3-center w3-row-padding content RED">
    <div class="w3-col w3-hide-medium  w3-hide-small l4">
      <h3>PICK YOUR TRUCK</h3>
      <p>We have the right truck for the load! <br> View Our Fleet</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col w3-hide-medium w3-hide-small l4">
      <h3>WORK FOR US</h3>
      <p>Become a Freight Broker<br> View Benefits/Application</p>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-coll l4">
      <h3>CONTACT US</h3>
      <p>Can't find what you're looking for?<br> Call/Email a Representative</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lovely solution! Thank you very much! Also, thank you for breaking down what you changed. :)

Comment: Your'e very welcome. When you gain more experience, try experimenting with the `w3.css` file. Despite it's overuse of `!important`, it covers the basics very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
.main-header {position: fixed; width: 100%;}
```

Then adjust the css for the other container to look how it want it to look.

Comment: That definitely worked after I tinkered around with it, however, the image now spans the whole length of the page. I can see it in spaces between divs, whereas before, I could not.